# curl unexpected results, unknown error

Tags: php, curl, centos5

I have a vps with centos 5.4 and php ver 5.2.17.
Oddly enough curl is not working correctly on this server.
This code:

```
<?php
$creq = curl_init();
curl_setopt($creq, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.nonexistent.zong");
curl_exec($creq);

if (curl_errno($creq)) {
echo "err";
print curl_error($creq);
} else { echo "ok";
curl_close($creq);
}
?>
```

oddly enough returns ok!!!
On my local server where tests are fine I have php 5.4 so I was thinking maybe that's the case IDK.

Any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: So exactly what is the problem?

Comment: Any error returned by `curl_error()` ?

Comment: no nothing returned from curl_errno()!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe curl is not activated on your distant server.

Your functions returns "ok" if there is no curl_errno($creq), which will probably be the case if curl can't be found.

Your functions pretty much acts like:

```
if (i get an error from curl) { print error }
else { print ok }
```

If there is no curl, you will not get an error from curl... So if I were you I would check if curl is enabled on your distant server.

Comment: use `phpinfo()` to check whether cURL installed & enabled

Comment: Yes, it seems curl is installed:
curl
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
It seems like the curl version was outdated and this command did the trick:

```
yum install php-curl
```

My best guess is that there was a bug in the previous version.